# Applicability of tests of convergence for series with non-negative terms

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We know that there are many criteria of convergence for series with non-negative terms (for example, ratio test (with limit), root test (with limit), integral, comparison, and asymptotic comparison, etc). Could you clarify if these tests yield corret results if the series has non-negative terms only for $n>\nu$, for some $\nu \in \mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, since $\sum_{n=\nu+1}^\infty a_n$ will converge by the appropriate test and the previous terms will add up to a finite sum.

More formally let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence such that $a_n\ge0$ for $n>\nu$ and such
that $\sum_{n=\nu+1}^\infty a_n$ converges to $A$ by an appropriate test for a series with non-negative terms. Then

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n=a_0+\ldots+a_\nu+\sum_{k=\nu+1}^\infty a_n=a_0+\ldots+a_\nu+A.$$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. But in practice, what should I write (to make it as formal as possible) when I do an exercise to indicate that I'm applying the criterion for this reason and that therefore it is not necessary to study the absolute convergence?

Comment: I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your quite welcome.